# Showcasing website to others

Tags: html, web, publish

I've made a website for an event me and about 10 other people will be organizing. We don't have a domain yet, so I can't publish it yet. (We don't want to publish it yet too, because our promotion timeframe hasn't started yet.)

My question is how can I 'showcase' it to others ? Something like JsFiddle, but then for a whole website. It's a one page website, which uses HTML, CSS, JQuery, and some external fonts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about site promotion.

Comment: It's not about promotion, I want to share it with about 10 other people in the organization for testing purposes.

Comment: I see, but it is still off-topic because it will attract opinion based answers and is also too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a domain and hosting and upload it there.

You can then setup your page in a subfolder in `public_html` so the link would be `yoursite.com\top-secret\`. You could also setup a password protect for that folder using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` so it could only be seen by people who have a username and password.

**.htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /home/username/public_html/top-secret/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

**.htpasswd**

```
username:password
```

Comment: Ok, I was hoping that there was another way, but we have to get the domain eventually..

Comment: It's really the best, most secure and most simple way IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bitbucket.

[source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Publishing+a+Website+on+Bitbucket)

you should follow these steps

1. Log into your Bitbucket account.
2. Create a repository and making sure to Name it using the following format:
   accountname.bitbucket.org
3. clone your repository to your local system
4. make your changes (in your case add the index.html file to the root directory)
5. commit the change, and push the result to Bitbucket

now you can see your website on accountname.bitbucket.org